# iTunes Connect Sales and Trends Delay?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store-connect

I have a paid application on the App Store, which when a user downloads, creates a new "user" in my database. From this database, I see that I had approximately 140 new devices added yesterday, which means 140 new people have purchased my app.

However, when in iTunes Connect, I only see 1 sale for yesterday. Is there some sort of delay in them displaying sales data for a day?

Or is it possible that my paid App has just been released on some jailbroken app store for free?

Just wondering if anyone has experienced this, and what they did to figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: I find that there is typically a 24-48 hour delay in getting full daily stats downloaded off iTunes Connect. @FelixLam has made some good additional points regarding multiple devices belonging to the same Apple ID, and jailbroken devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be a delay and more importantly depending on your time zone a different definition of the day yesterday.

One purchase can be downloaded to any device that is registered to this user. E.g. if I buy your app I can copy it to my iPhone, iPad and iPod.

Jailbroken apps also account for a large number of downloads.

These three factors are likely to explain the difference.

Comment: All that makes sense, however, the gap in sales data seems way too large for just a timezone difference. I'll wait and see what my reports look like tomorrow... but im thinking my app has been jailbroken =/

Comment: all our apps have been jailbroken, so either your app is unsuccessful or it has been jailbroken ;)